# How to put java results into a file (i.e. Excel)

Tags: java, excel

So the code below when ran lists all the url links to a website as well as the page's url that each set of links come from. So how would I be able to store these links somewhere like say an Excel file or any type of file if it can't be excel?

public class Crawler {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Set<String> visitedUrls = new HashSet<>();
String url = "http://www.claflin.edu";
crawl(url, visitedUrls);


  private static void crawl(String url, Set<String> visited) throws IOException {
if(url.isEmpty() || visited.contains(url)) {
    return;
}
print("Fetching %s...", url);
visited.add(url);
Document doc;



 try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10000).get();
} catch (UnsupportedMimeTypeException e) {
    System.out.println("Unsupported Mime type. Aborting crawling for URL: " + url);
    return;
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    System.out.println("Unsupported protocol for URL: " + url);
    return;
} catch (HttpStatusException e) {
    System.out.println("Error (status=" + e.getStatusCode() + ") fetching URL: " + url);
    return;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Timeout fetching URL: " + url);
    return;
}

Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
Elements links1 = doc.select("a[href$=\".pdf\"]");
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

print("\nOther Links: (%d)", links1.size());
for (Element link: links1){
    print(" * a: <%s> (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
}

print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
for (Element link: links)
{
    print(" * a: <%s> (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
}

  for(Element link : links) {
    String href = link.attr("abs:href");
    URL hrefURL = null;
    try {
        hrefURL = new URL(href);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        //nothing
    }
    if(hrefURL != null && hrefURL.getHost().equals(new URL(url).getHost())) {
        crawl(href, visited);
    }

   }
  }


private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
  }

private static String trim(String s, int width) {
if (s.length() > width)
    return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
else
    return s;

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). It supports creation of Excel files (xsl, xslx). [Here](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) you can finde more information about the used XSSF and HSSF format. Code examples can be found [here](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html)